# I get dizzy & light headed when go into store which sells helium ballons

Tags: reaction-mechanism

I get dizzy when I go into a party store which sells helium ballons and need to get to fresh air outside ASAP. Am I sensitive to helium or why does this happen. I feel like I am going to fall down and very shaky on my feet while trying to get to door to leave the store.  Have had this happen at two party stores. If it is not helium sensitivity have not idea what causes it.

Comment: It's very hard to imagine a biochemical mechanism for helium sensitivity. Even if the correlation is real, it's **vastly** more likely you're making a wrong inference, and something other than helium is causing the effects - an unblinded qualitative statistical study with n = 2 samples isn't good enough evidence for that rather unusual hypothesis.

Comment: Shops that sell helium balloons *also* sell many other unusual items. How do you know the cause of your dizziness is helium?

Answer (score 5):

Helium itself is inert, with *no* physiological clue to its presence. That has caused [death of workers](https://www.latimes.com/socal/burbank-leader/news/tn-blr-xpm-2000-02-02-export18177-story.html) inside dirigibles and [of these students](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC2563455/). There is no smell, dizziness, or other sensation caused by helium, and that can be dangerous.

Here is another possibility: some businesses employ ultrasonic door openers and intrusion detection. Ultrasonic vibration can bother some people's middle ears, throwing off balance -- this happened to an acquaintance as we entered a department store. Walking back and forth, we quickly found the ultrasonic source. Is it possible that while filling balloons, an ultrasonic squeal is emitted? You could get or make a simple [ultrasound converter](https://www.incbtech.com/index.php/articles/79-bionics-and-medicine/466-ultrasonic-sound-converter-hearing-the-unheard-bm013) to check... and have fun listening to bats, [mice](https://royalsocietypublishing.org/doi/10.1098/rsbl.2009.0317), and dolphins, too.